# MUI: align and justify image center inside flex box

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

Why is my image aligned center, but not justified? im confused..

```
<Box
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        minHeight: '100vh',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexGrow: 1,
      }}>
      <Container maxWidth="sm">
        <img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/001/200/294/original/house-png.png"
          width={200}
          alt="img"
        />
        <LinearProgress sx={{ mt: 4 }} />
      </Container>
    </Box>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `img` with `Box`

```
<Box
  sx={{
    display: 'flex',
    minHeight: '100vh',
    alignItems: "center",
    flexGrow: 1,
  }}
>
  <Container maxWidth="sm">
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: "center"
      }}
    >
      <img
        src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/001/200/294/original/house-png.png"
        width={200}
        alt="img"
      />
    </Box>
    <LinearProgress sx={{ mt: 4 }} />
  </Container>
</Box>
```

Look at my demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4zagd9?file=demo.tsx)

[image]

Comment: @Lizzal leave me any feedback

Answer (score 1):

If you want to justify content centred, you have to use "justifyContent: 'center'" property. Also the "Container" element was having some issues, you can use .

Check if this what you want to achieve

```
<Box
  sx={{
    display: "flex",
    minHeight: "100vh",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flexGrow: 1
  }}
>
  <Box>
    <img
      src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/001/200/294/original/house-png.png"
      width={200}
      alt="img"
    />
    <LinearProgress sx={{ mt: 4 }} />
  </Box>
</Box>
```

[Demo on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-forked-7xcpdd?file=/index.js)